# Python-gcm issue with no response from GCM server

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I am currently trying to finish implementing Android push notifications with python-gcm and am running into issues where I am not getting a response from the GCM server when I push the notifications.

I have verified that I am getting the device_id, and that the API key / sender ID's being used are correct, and I am getting a successful response back once I hit the GCM server, but I still see no push notifications showing up on my device.

Is this usually just because the way I have the GCM set up in the Google Developer Console is not correct?

First time implementing this so I'm sure there may just be something common I've missed.

Below is the sample flask-gcm code that I have set up. I am receiving a success response back, there must be something missing on the google setup side I am thinking.

```
 if device.platform == 'Android':
        # data = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}
        data = {'data': message}

        # Set the device id
        reg_id = device.device_id

        Logger.info('Before sending the push JSON ' + str(reg_id))

        # Pass in the reg id of who to send to
        multicast = JSONMessage([reg_id], data, dry_run=False)

        try:
            # attempt send
            res_multicast = gcm_service.send(multicast)

            for res in [res_multicast]:
                # nothing to do on success
                for reg_id, msg_id in res.success.items():
                    Logger.info("Successfully sent %s as %s" % (reg_id, msg_id))
                    Logger.info("THIS IS THE REG ID THAT WAS SENT TO: " + str(reg_id))
                    Logger.info("THIS IS THE MESSAGE ID THAT WAS SENT " + str(msg_id))
                    Logger.info("RES SUCESS ITEMS: " + str(res.success.items()))

                # update your registration ID's
                for reg_id, new_reg_id in res.canonical.items():
                    Logger.info("Replacing %s with %s in database" % (reg_id, new_reg_id))

                # probably app was uninstalled
                for reg_id in res.not_registered:
                    Logger.info("Removing %s from database" % reg_id)

                # unrecoverably failed, these ID's will not be retried
                # consult GCM manual for all error codes
                for reg_id, err_code in res.failed.items():
                    Logger.info("Removing %s because %s" % (reg_id, err_code))

                # if some registration ID's have recoverably failed
                if res.needs_retry():
                    # construct new message with only failed regids
                    retry_msg = res.retry()
                    # you have to wait before attemting again. delay()
                    # will tell you how long to wait depending on your
                    # current retry counter, starting from 0.
                    # Logger.info("Wait or schedule task after %s seconds" % res.delay(retry))
                    # retry += 1 and send retry_msg again

        except GCMAuthenticationError:
                # stop and fix your settings
                print "Your Google API key is rejected"
        except ValueError, e:
                # probably your extra options, such as time_to_live,
                # are invalid. Read error message for more info.
                print "Invalid message/option or invalid GCM response"
                print e.args[0]
        except Exception:
                # your network is down or maybe proxy settings
                # are broken. when problem is resolved, you can
                # retry the whole message.
                print "Something wrong with requests library"
```

Comment: not sure what steps you have followed. But Cloud Messaging should be enabled from the Google Console and you have valid server key generated from the console.

Comment: I've finished both of those steps and verified. One thing that I did do was leave the "Allowed IP's" field blank when generating the server key.

Comment: thats good. nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I commented out when I was testing using the plaintext request.

Comment: Seems correct. Are you using debug keystore key or production?

Comment: I believe I am using debug keystore key, are the device id's generated with the debug keystore key not able to be used for testing push notifications?

Comment: Just making sure. It should work

Comment: Are you sure no error showing up ?

Comment: Positive, the only thing that is being logged out is the empty "response" {} No exceptions, the job finishes all the way through just doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Well thats a strange behaviour, either it should throw exception or deliver the message, in either case it should return response.

Comment: On this page https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm it shows to handle errors.

Comment: I updated the code block to show the new flask-gcm code that I am using. I am able to get a "SUCCESS" response back, but still not push notifications are being sent to my device.

Comment: with success you will get the id of successfull message, are you getting that ?

Comment: Yes I am, I can verify that I am being returned the message id, I am just not sure what is missing now to get the push to actually go to the device =/

Comment: definitely something wrong with you device. try different device.

Comment: {"multicast_id":8634598534004158065,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1429617116554691%2b9ae662f9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: That is the response that I am receiving.

Comment: its means its getting pushed successfully,.

Comment: I've Linked my sender key on my google play developer console now, that was part of the problem. I had a key but never linked it up. I am still unsure whether for testing if I have to build the release apk to my device then test?